# Eclipse RCP: Plugin does not start

Tags: plugins, eclipse-rcp

I wrote a new plugin for my eclipse rcp application and added the plugin to the dependencies of my product. I also tried to set the auto-start value of the new plugin to true but it does not start. It shows up as resolved but not as started.

Basically the only thing that this plugin does is to add a help file (table of contents) via the extension point `org.eclipse.help.toc`.

Any idea why the plugin code isn't executed?

Also: the plugin adds its content if I execute it from inside eclipse. The problem occures after I export it.

Comment: I'm really getting desperate on this issue. When running my application from within the IDE it works perfectly fine but as soon as I export my product it does not show the help menu entry. I'm using the same plugin dependencies for my runtime configuration and for the product configuration. Any ideas what I am missing would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear ... you're not expecting 'code' to run, but when you launch the exported RCP application standalone, the help contents does not appear in the TOC, right?

How did you define your RCP product?  As a feature or plug-in based product?

If based on plug-in's, did you define all the necessary plug-in's on the product dependencies tab?

If based on features, did you add the new plug-in to the feature?

Comment: Yes you are right the help doesn't appear. It is a plug-in based product. I added the same dependencies to my product as to my regular eclipse launch configuration. When I start it from within eclispe it is fine but when I export it the help content is missing. For now I stuffd the help content into another one of my plugins which works fine. It just sucks that I wasn't able to use the architecture I had planned (Custom plugin for the help content).